# SMTP Outgoing IP ( source ip )

Tags: python, smtp

I'm trying to change the outgoing smtp ip address, i succeeded to change ip address using source_address=(host,port)

example :         `smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587,source_address=('185.193.157.60',12323)`

But i can't find **how to add username and password of the proxy** ( if the proxy requires username and password )

I tried : `smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587,source_address=('185.193.157.60',12323, 'username', 'password')`

**But it didn't work**

Answer (score 0):

From the docs...

SMTP.login(user, password, *, initial_response_ok=True)

Comment: SMTP.login comes after smtplib.SMTP
I'm looking to connect a user from different ip address, and sometimes the proxy (ip address) requires username and password for auth